# C++ coverage tool that WORKS?

Tags: visual-c++, code-coverage

Been searching for a good coverage tool for a while now.

I'm with VC++ 2008.

Tried already:
NCover, PureCoverage, PartCover and a few others I can't remember their names.

None works!
Not even with a very basic console application that does almost nothing.

Tried to get an evaluation copy from BullsEye and few more others - not only that they require you to ask for it (no automatic process), they don't even answer after you request AND after you ask what's going on, through the support mail.

So the question is: **Is there any tool, which I can immediately download** an evaluation for it, that actually **works on VC 2008** projects? Something that will **get me going within 10 minutes**? It's funny but it seems to be a very non-trivial request in the area of this kind of software.

Comment: I'm assuming that since NCover didn't work you're not talking about a .NET application?

Comment: Native C++. Compiled with VC++ 2008.

Comment: Considering that you posted this at what appears to be early Saturday morning, I'm not suprised that places for you've asked for downloads from haven't responded.   They might on Monday.

Comment: No, asked for it about wednesday.

Comment: PartCover is also only for .NET applications (all languages supported)

Comment: https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/ I haven't tried it but maybe others can comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to ask for it... but it does work:

[SD C++ Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html)

EDIT May 2011: Downloads available for since late 2010.